# How to eliminate a django form's prefix when rendering only the field's name, but keeping everything else untouched

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, prefix

In some views of my Django app, two instances of the same form are rendered, one is included via a context processor, and the other is included by the view. The only difference between the two forms are the styling and position, they have the same fields and submit to the same view.

Then I notices that the IDs of the elements are the same, and some functionality, like the label click that focus the corresponding field, behaves wrong, like focusing the same field on the other form. Then I added a form prefix to the first form and of course the labels worked again.

But the prefix is also applied to the fields names (besides the IDs), and therefore, the view that get the submitted data didn't work, since the form instance was initialized without the prefix. Also, the query string looks even weirder :(

I'm looking for a solution that keeps the original fields names, not prefixed, and still use prefixed HTML IDs, so the view keeps working unchanged. Or any other way of rendering two forms with isolated ids but the same field names.

Answer (score 1):

[using prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms) is useful to have several Django forms in a single <form> element.

If you want to have more than one <form> element, you may use [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/formsets/).

Comment: I want to render the same form twice. The example is Google, which duplicates the same form ate the top ad bottom of the results page.

Comment: To have twice the same forms, but with labels that match the right form element, you need differents ids for each element. So you can use Formset with extra=2 to get twice your form with different ids for each element.